# Fixed width content with flexible (strechable) sidebar

Tags: html, css

Rather than trying to explain this - which would be hard I have created an image - I am having trouble creating a layout in which:
The sidebar is flexible and can extend to fill the empty space not consumed by the content fiv which has a fixed width of 725px.

Have a look at the image please :)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little positioning witchcraft, seems to match your picture: right part has fixed width 200px, the left one takes the rest (but never smaller than 100px).

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 310px;
}

#container .left {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 210px;
    height: 200px;
}

#container .content {
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">a</div>
    <div class="content">b</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nzd2J/2/. Move vertical splitting bar to see how it scales.

Comment: @nikita-rybak I think the boxes are supposed to be the other way around. :P

Comment: @Shaz What do you mean? I've only reduced size a little (725->200, etc). Anyway, your example works nicely too.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak Never mind, guess my eyes were just playing tricks on me. Though, when your example has more content than the height, the boxes stay the same.

Comment: @Nikita-Rybak that's perfect! Thanks @Shaz but it seems your right div is felixble i needed the left one to be as per Nikita's response.

Comment: This falls apart, if you need a variable height and the absolutely positioned element is higher than the statically one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/GaZYt/1/

Html:

```
<div id="contain">
    <div id="left">
        Left <br /> <br /> <br />
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contain {
    width 100%;   
}

#contain #left {
    min-width: 185px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
}

#contain #right {
    min-width: 725px;       
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}
```